# Django not recognized in virtual environment altough already installed when inside virtual environment

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I've created a virtual environment in my PC(Windows). I've pushed the project to my git repository and now cloned it into my Mac. I activated the virtual environment, and tried running :

python3 manage.py runserver

This error is raised :

```
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I understand that the message sent from above is defined inside the manage.py if an ImportError is raised.

What I'm trying to understand is how to make the project to be runnable from multiple systems just by activating the virtual environment.

AFTER cloning the project, I've changed line in my :

pyvenv.cfg

```
...
include-system-site-packages = true
//previously = false
...
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong while setting up the virtual environment and installing the packages while being IN the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your windows pc, inside the activated virtual environment, run

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Add this file to your git and push it to your repository.

After that, in your mac environment, pull the latest git changes and inside the activated virtual environment, run:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

If pip3 is not recognized, use `pip`

Finally, run `python3 manage.py runserver`

Comment: going to take some time to update trying out this method ; i dont have access to my windows pc right now :')

Comment: Use `pip install django` on your mac

Comment: it worked! i just ran pip3 freeze > requirements.txt in my mac, then ran the 2nd command you gave in my virtual environment. thanks for your help :)